# Setting default date in Datebox in textfield and calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

I have a date field from datebox (from [dev.jtsage.com](http://dev.jtsage.com)) that I am using with jquery mobile

1 - How do I set the default value in the text box and the calendar to todays date? Also have to disable all the previous dates.

I Have tried

```
var defaultPickerValue = new Date();
$('#mydate').datebox({'defaultValue': defaultPickerValue});
```

But this doesn't set the value in the text field.
What should I do  to disable all the previous dates?

2 - Secondly,  I have a 2 date fields. On selecting date on first field the date in second field should set automatically. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable all the previous dates, try this:

```
$("#mydate").datebox({"mode":"calbox", "useNewStyle":true, "afterToday":true});
```

And to set defaultValue, please look at http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/ >> Common Options

```
defaultValue    Default value for the date - e.g. [2001,1,1] or 13:42   false   Array/String    -ALL
```

Comment: yeah, the old options documentation was incredibly ugly.  Changed the link to the new docs.  Specific option would be here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/index.php?idx=common&key=defaultValue